# extract files inside zip sub folders with python zipfile

Tags: python, pandas, python-zipfile

i have a zip folder that contains files and child zip folders. I am able to read the files placed in the parent folder but how can i get to the files inside the child zip folders? here is my code to get the files inside the parent folder

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import requests
import zipfile
url1 = 'https://www.someurl.com/abc.zip'
r = requests.get(url1)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))    
temp  = pd.read_csv(z.open('mno.csv')
```

my question is, if lets say, I have a child sub folder

```
xyz.zip
```

containing file

```
pqr.csv
```

how can I read this file

Answer (score 1):

Use another `BytesIO` object to open the contained zipfile

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import requests
import zipfile

# Read outer zip file
url1 = 'https://www.someurl.com/abc.zip'
r = requests.get(url1)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(r.content))

# lets say the archive is:
#     zippped_folder/pqr.zip (which contains pqr.csv)

# Read contained zip file
pqr_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(z.open('zippped_folder/pqr.zip')))
temp = pd.read_csv(pqr_zip.open('prq.csv'))
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying some permutation-combination, i hatched the problem with this code

```
zz = zipfile.ZipFile(z.namelist()[i])
temp2  = pd.read_csv(zz.open('pqr.csv'))
# where i is the index position of the child zip folder in the namelist() list. In this case, the 'xyz.zip' folder

# for eg if the 'xyz.zip' folder was third in the list, the command would be:
zz = zipfile.ZipFile(z.namelist()[2])
```

alternatively, if the index position is not known, the same can be achieved like this:

```
zz  = zipfile.ZipFile(z.namelist()[z.namelist().index('xyz.zip')])
```