# How to open a csv in a zip in a zip with python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, zip

I have been using a user-defined function to open CSV files contained within a ZIP file, which has been working very well for me.

[How to scrape .csv files from a url, when they are saved in a .zip file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843761/how-to-scrape-csv-files-from-a-url-when-they-are-saved-in-a-zip-file-in-pytho/48844157?noredirect=1#comment88976276_48844157)

Now I am trying to open a CSV file which is contained within a ZIP, which is contained in another ZIP, and have run into some trouble.

Instead of getting the expected output of a dataframe with the data from a CSV, I am getting this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 0: invalid start byte
```

which sort of makes sense because I am trying to open a zip file with `read_csv()`

```
import pandas as pd

def fetch_multi_csv_zip_from_url(url, filenames=(), *args, **kwargs):
    assert kwargs.get('compression') is None
    req = urlopen(url)
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(req.read()))

    if filenames:
        names = zip_file.namelist()
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename not in names:
                raise ValueError(
                    'filename {} not in {}'.format(filename, names))
    else:
        filenames = zip_file.namelist()

    return {name: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name), *args, **kwargs)
            for name in filenames}

try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

final_links_list =['http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20170523.zip', 'http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20170524.zip']
l = len(final_links_list)

for j in range(0,l):
    print(j)
    dfs = fetch_multi_csv_zip_from_url(final_links_list[j])
```

This is the code that I have been using, and I gather that I have to change the line starting with:

```
return {name: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name)
```

as it no longer returns a csv file, but a zip file.

Comment: I have tried following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40009022/extract-files-inside-zip-sub-folders-with-python-zipfile but have got lost, again because the object is a zip file, rather than a csv, not sure how to go back and open the zip file

Comment: Then you need another 'zipfile.ZipFile` on the nested zip object.

Comment: This is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as there is no example data to used for testing, nor is there expected output.

Comment: Sorry, still getting used to what to put in an MCVE, is this any better?

Comment: If someone runs the above code does it exhibit the error?  If no, then it is not MCVE.  Not V, verifiable.  Also it is helpful to show what you would expect the result to be if it were to be working correctly.

Comment: right, that is a good point, now it does

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have tried using 
return {name: pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(zip_file.open(name)), *args, **kwargs)
but then I get this error, KeyError: "There is no item named <zipfile.ZipExtFile name='PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_201705230010_0000000283825976.zip' mode='r' compress_type=deflate> in the archive"

Comment: How do I just extract the name with the first zip_file.open()

Comment: @LukaVlaskalic: My apologies, I meant `zipfile.ZipFile()`.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I misunderstood what you were saying. That sounds about right, I will check that when I get home. I assume that would go in line 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with a bit of recursion. If a file inside a ZIP is found to be a ZIP file, then make a recursive call to extract CSV files:

```
try:
    from urllib.request import urlopen
except ImportError:
    from urllib2 import urlopen

from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

import pandas as pd

# Dictionary holding all the dataframes from all zip/zip/csvs
dfs = {}


def zip_to_dfs(data):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(data))

    for name in zip_file.namelist():
        if name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
            dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name))
        elif name.lower().endswith('.zip'):
            zip_to_dfs(zip_file.open(name).read())


def get_zip_data_from_url(url):
    req = urlopen(url)
    zip_to_dfs(req.read())


final_links_list = [
    'http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20170523.zip', 
    'http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20170524.zip']

for link in final_links_list:
    print(link)
    get_zip_data_from_url(link)

# Display the first couple of dataframes    
for name, df in sorted(dfs.items())[:2]:
    print('\n', name, '\n')
    print(df)
```

This would display the following:

```
http://www.nemweb.com.au/REPORTS/ARCHIVE/Dispatch_SCADA/PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_20170524.zip

 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_201705240010_0000000283857084.CSV 

     C     NEMP.WORLD DISPATCHSCADA  AEMO               PUBLIC 2017/05/24  \
0    I       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0       SETTLEMENTDATE       DUID   
1    D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:10:00    BARCSF1   
2    D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:10:00   BUTLERSG   
..  ..            ...           ...   ...                  ...        ...   
263  D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:10:00      YWPS3   
264  D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:10:00      YWPS4   
265  C  END OF REPORT           267   NaN                  NaN        NaN   

       00:05:08  0000000283857084  DISPATCHSCADA.1  0000000283857078  
0    SCADAVALUE               NaN              NaN               NaN  
1             0               NaN              NaN               NaN  
2      8.299998               NaN              NaN               NaN  
..          ...               ...              ...               ...  
263  388.745570               NaN              NaN               NaN  
264  391.568360               NaN              NaN               NaN  
265         NaN               NaN              NaN               NaN  

[266 rows x 10 columns]

 PUBLIC_DISPATCHSCADA_201705240015_0000000283857169.CSV 

     C     NEMP.WORLD DISPATCHSCADA  AEMO               PUBLIC 2017/05/24  \
0    I       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0       SETTLEMENTDATE       DUID   
1    D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:15:00    BARCSF1   
2    D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:15:00   BUTLERSG   
..  ..            ...           ...   ...                  ...        ...   
263  D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:15:00      YWPS3   
264  D       DISPATCH    UNIT_SCADA   1.0  2017/05/24 00:15:00      YWPS4   
265  C  END OF REPORT           267   NaN                  NaN        NaN   

       00:10:08  0000000283857169  DISPATCHSCADA.1  0000000283857163  
0    SCADAVALUE               NaN              NaN               NaN  
1             0               NaN              NaN               NaN  
2      8.299998               NaN              NaN               NaN  
..          ...               ...              ...               ...  
263  386.205080               NaN              NaN               NaN  
264  389.592410               NaN              NaN               NaN  
265         NaN               NaN              NaN               NaN  

[266 rows x 10 columns]
```