# Read two files inside a .zip URL: delete the PDF, keep the CSV

Tags: python, python-requests, pycharm, zip

I want to download, save and clean a set of datasets that are storaged as .zip files in more than **150 URLs**. My function follows the package documentation like this:

```py
import requests

def download_url(url, save_path, chunk_size = 128):

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=chunk_size):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

But this is not working. Issue: **'requests.get' doesn't return what I need**. I think that might occur because there are two distinct files in the .zip: a .csv and a .pdf. **Is it there a way to read both files, delete the .pdf, and save only the .csv?**

Comment: GET does the job, thats what browsers do actually when fetching (downloading) a content. Not sure whats up with your case. Please elaborate further.

Comment: I thought so too. But then I tested:  >>>   r = resquests.get ('https://EXAMPLE.zip', stream = TRUE)  >>> print(r) >>> r =[200]. Not my  data unfornately...

Comment: can you give a concrete example (including an actual URL) that fails to work?

Comment: Absolutely. It is a bit more complex, but still not returning the data the way I need it unfortunately.`import requests, zipfile37, io

test = requests.get('https://cdn.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/votacao_secao/votacao_secao_2014_RJ.zip', stream=True)
z = zipfile37.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(test.content))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below did it for me:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile37
import pandas as pd
dfs = {}
req = urlopen('https://cdn.tse.jus.br/estatistica/sead/odsele/votacao_secao/votacao_secao_2014_RJ.zip')
data = req.read()

zip_file = zipfile37.ZipFile(BytesIO(data))
for name in zip_file.namelist():
    if name.lower().endswith('.txt'):
        dfs[name] = pd.read_csv(zip_file.open(name), sep=";", header=None, encoding='latin1')
```

Its a tweek from [How to open a csv in a zip in a zip with python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991084/how-to-open-a-csv-in-a-zip-in-a-zip-with-python)

Thanks!